# Nexus 9 - How do I change the cellular band?

Tags: connection-issues, mobile-network, data-connection, 4g, nexus-9

I've got an international edition 32GB Nexus 9 LTE. It appears to be unable to connect to 3.5G / HSPA+  networks, as a result, I get poor data speeds (3G is pretty slow for my requirements). I've got a Nexus 7, LG G2 and LG G3 all on the same carrier as the N9, and they can all connect to 3.5G / HSPA+ in the areas where the Nexus 9 struggles.

On regular phones, I would overcome this issue by dialling *#*#4636#*#* and changing the preferred bands, however, since the Nexus 9 doesn't have a dialler, I'm unable to access this menu. Any ideas on alternative ways I could get to this menu? Maybe via a third-party app or a terminal command?

I'm running Android 6.0.1 and have root access.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you test these commands? `adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.RadioInfo --user 0` -- this should open "Phone Information" page. Alternatively, `adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.TestingSettings --user 0` -- this should open "Testing" page, the same page launched from that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I installed a third-party dialler app (Truedialler), and I was able to dial *#*#4636#*#* and change the band and preferred network mode.